# How to sort an array of different object types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model JournalDay with two sub-models: journal_entries and completed_to_dos.

I have created a method journal_entries_and_to_dos that combines all journal_entries and to_dos for a given JournalDay, but I can't figure out how to sort it given that I need to sort by different object variable names: journal_entries.created_at and to_dos.completed_at.

I've gotten as far as the code below to create the array of combined journal_entries_and_to_dos. How could I go about sorting it by journal_entries.created_at and completed_to_dos.completed_at?

```
class JournalDay < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :journal_entries
  has_many :completed_to_dos, -> { where.not(completed_at: [nil,""]) }, class_name: 'ToDo'

  def journal_entries_and_completed_to_dos
    combined = []
    self.journal_entries.each do |journal_entry|
      combined << journal_entry
    end
    self.completed_to_dos.each do |completed_to_do|
      combined << completed_to_do
    end
  end
```

Comment: You should really start by applying a decent schema to the table so that `completed_at` is a datestamp/timestamp type column and not a string. There is no reason in the world a column with that name should ever contain "".

Comment: You can also just do `self.journal_entries + self.completed_to_dos` or `self.journal_entries.concat(self.completed_to_dos)` instead of those two meaningless loops. If you are calling `.each` and modifying an outside variable in Ruby you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following is working:

`combined.sort_by { |obj| obj.class == "ToDo" ? obj.completed_at : obj.created_at }`

This essentially uses sort_by where we use "completed_at" if the object class is "ToDo" otherwise we use "created_at" as the sorting variable.